# angular form with switcher with one input

Tags: angular

I have component with switcher of parts, in which user should fill input field (T1, T2, T3). 
T1 is opened by default. Earlier after filling Part1 user clicked submit and data goes to server, than clicked T2 - submit, than clicked T3 - submit. Now I need send values, after filling all parts, but when I fill T1 submit button becomes active, click T2 input field becomes clear and submit button becomes disabled.

Is it possible with form with one input to get all 3 values and than send them on submit.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="value.PartId == activatedPart">
    <app-send-value [activatedPart]="activatedPart"></app-send-value>
</ng-container> 

and in <app-send-value> I have form with mat-input


    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput
                   type="number"
                   required
                   value="{{value}}"
                   [(ngModel)]="value">
        </mat-form-field>

            <button type="submit"
                    [disabled]="sendValue.invalid">
                Submit
            </button>
    </form>
```

[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD3WZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update based on your stackblitz example : Please modify as follows

send.component.html :

```
<form class="value-form"
          id="sendValue"
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
          autocomplete="off"
          #sendValue="ngForm">
            <input matInput
                   class="value-input"
                   type="number"
                   name="value"
           placeholder="fill the field"
           onfocus="this.value=''"
                   id="value"
                   required
                   [(ngModel)]="value[activatedPart - 1]">
        <div class="send-form-buttons">
            <button class="app-btn-success-sm"
                    type="submit"
                    [disabled]="checkDisabled()">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

send.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-send',
  templateUrl: './send.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./send.component.css']
})
export class SendComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

@Input() activatedPart = 0;
@Input() switchesLength = 0;
value: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get formInvalid() {
        return false
    }

  onSubmit() {
        if (this.formInvalid) return;

    console.log(this.value)
  }

  checkDisabled() {
    if(Array.isArray(this.value) && this.value.length === 3) {
      return !this.value.every(function(element) {return !!element;}); 
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

You can clear the values on submit simply by writing `this.value = [];` on submit function and removing  `onfocus="this.value=''"` from `<input>` tag

Comment: Could you provide an example of binding, please (I`ve changed [(ngModel)]="value[TCount-1]" and I`m getting  only last value in array [empty × 2, 3])

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example with minimal code?

Comment: I have one input. In console [undefinied, undefined, value3] and I need [value1, value2, value3]

Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h4zra4

Comment: I've modified he answer. Please check.